# pandas dataframe reshape / pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I'd like to convert the following pandas dataframe

```
    a   b
0   1   2
1   1   5
2   2   4
3   1   3
4   3   7
5   2   1
```

to

```
    0   1   2
a           
1   2   5   3  
2   4   1   NaN
3   7   NaN NaN
```

Do you know an easy way?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see the pattern here. How exactly are the elements of the resulting matrix related to the original?

Comment: Suppose 'b' column shows blood pressure readings and 'a' column shows the patient id. I'd like to have all the readings from each patient in one line. Each patient may have from 1 to a maximum number of readings, say 10. So the final table will be of shape number_of_patients x 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this as follows:

```
In [11]: df.groupby("a")["b"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values))
Out[11]:
a
1  0    2
   1    5
   2    3
2  0    4
   1    1
3  0    7
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

to get the form you wanted you then unstack (though probably above better):

```
In [22]: df.groupby('a')["b"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack(1)
Out[22]:
     0    1    2
a
1  2.0  5.0  3.0
2  4.0  1.0  NaN
3  7.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks.